# How to adapt the command line in a miniconda3 environment in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

When activating any miniconda3 environment in Ubuntu (WSL2), also the command line is changed. Before activation, my command line looks like I have defined the `PS1` variable in my `.bashrc` file:

`username@workingdirectory$`

After activation, the command line has changed to:

`(base)username@pc:/path/working/directory$`

including a change in colors.

I would like to have the command line look similar to my original command line (including the colors), perhaps with only the name of the current conda enviroment added at the end of the command line. E.g.:
`username@workingdirectory (base)$`

I have already set the `changeps1` to `false` in `.condarc`, but this only removes the conda environment from the command line and still changes the rest of the command line (including colors).

Does anyone know how I can adapt the command line in conda environments to my wishes?

Edit as answer on @Edgar Magallan: the `$HOME/miniconda3/bin/activate` looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
_CONDA_ROOT="/home/username/miniconda3"
# Copyright (C) 2012 Anaconda, Inc
# SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause
\. "$_CONDA_ROOT/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" || return $?
conda activate "$@"
```

Edit 2: There are two places in my `conda.sh` file where PS1 is mentioned:

```
__conda_activate() {
if [ -n "${CONDA_PS1_BACKUP:+x}" ]; then
    # Handle transition from shell activated with conda <= 4.3 to a subsequent activation
    # after conda updated to >= 4.4. See issue #6173.
    PS1="$CONDA_PS1_BACKUP"
    \unset CONDA_PS1_BACKUP
fi
\local ask_conda
ask_conda="$(PS1="${PS1:-}" __conda_exe shell.posix "$@")" || \return
\eval "$ask_conda"
__conda_hashr
}
```

And:

```
if [ -z "${CONDA_SHLVL+x}" ]; then
   \export CONDA_SHLVL=0
   # In dev-mode CONDA_EXE is python.exe and on Windows
   # it is in a different relative location to condabin.
   if [ -n "${_CE_CONDA:+x}" ] && [ -n "${WINDIR+x}" ]; then
       PATH="$(\dirname "$CONDA_EXE")/condabin${PATH:+":${PATH}"}"
   else
       PATH="$(\dirname "$(\dirname "$CONDA_EXE")")/condabin${PATH:+":${PATH}"}"
   fi
   \export PATH

   # We're not allowing PS1 to be unbound. It must at least be set.
   # However, we're not exporting it, which can cause problems when starting a second shell
   # via a first shell (i.e. starting zsh from bash).
   if [ -z "${PS1+x}" ]; then
       PS1=
   fi
fi
```

Comment: What command are you using for activating `miniconda3`? And where is stored that command?

Comment: I use `source ~/.bashrc` to activate `miniconda3`. In my `.bashrc` file, the environment is activated with  `source $HOME/miniconda3/bin/activate`

Comment: Ok, can you now provide (in your question) the output of  `cat $HOME/miniconda3/bin/activate`?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon see the edit in the question description

Comment: Thanks, now I will need you provide the output of `cat /home/username/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`. I think that's the file where the bash prompt changes.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499220/anaconda-disable-prompt-change)?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon See the edits

Comment: I think the possible solution (if none worked for you) would be to save into some variable  the  value of `PS1` before the line `source $HOME/miniconda3/bin/activate` (in your **~/.bashrc**). And after that line (`source $HOME...`) you should reassign the value of PS1.